# how to extract a value from JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I have programmed my ruby on rails app to make a json document like what is needed to use on the following sample Google maps markers

this includes the file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.website.com/files/Hotload.json">
```

Example: Hotloads.json:

```
var data={"count":1733,"photos":[{"id":106368,"origin":"albany, ky","dest":"monett, mo","origin_lat":"-85.12171173095703","origin_lng":"36.75173568725586","dest_lat":"-93.94647216796875","dest_lng":"36.9279670715332","equipment":"Reefer"}]}
```

I want to pull out the value of `count`  witch in this example is `1733`

I have tried to do this:

```
data.count
```

with no luck

these work thou:

```
var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.origin_lng,
    dataPhoto.origin_lat);
```

UPDATE>>

Forgot Semicolon...

Got it now

Comment: if `data.photos[i]` works, then `data.count` should also work.

Comment: With the same object (data) a simple console.log(data.count) worked for me. ( with a semi colon at the end of the object ).

Comment: thanks guys forgot the semicolon

Comment: Sometimes its the little things, good luck.